# SystemError: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException:

Tags: java, python, importerror

I'm trying to learn some Korean NLP by using KoNLPy library.
This is the code that I used:

```
from konlpy.tag import Kkma  
kkma=Kkma()  
print(kkma.morphs("열심히 코딩한 당신, 연휴에는 여행을 가봐요"))
```

And I keep seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Study\NLP\2_tokenization.py", line 65, in <module>
kkma=Kkma()
File "C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\konlpy\tag\_kkma.py", line 95, in __init__
jvm.init_jvm(jvmpath, max_heap_size)
File "C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\konlpy\jvm.py", line 64, in init_jvm
jpype.startJVM(jvmpath, '-Djava.class.path=%s' % classpath,
File "C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 221, in startJVM
_jpype.startup(jvmpath, tuple(args),
SystemError: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 52: 
C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\*
```

But since I'm only at the beginning level and only just familiar with python, I can't figure out why this is happening. It seems like a problem related with JAVA.

Comment: have you installed all the dependencies - https://konlpy.org/en/latest/install/

Comment: try jpype1 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I'm a beginner to so I nearly gave up, but I played around with some of the code in the konlpy module itself and got it working! Here's the fix:

1. Go to konlpy's jvm.py file (i.e.
   "C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\konlpy\jvm.py").
2. In the init_jvm function, go to the section where folder_suffix is
   defined.
3. Under the "# Java sources" comment and the "# Twitter (Okt)"
   comment, there is a line with a string that contains an asterisk.
4. Delete those asterisks (2 total).

It's mmmmprobably not a perfect solution because I have no idea what those asterisks were doing there in the first place, so I'm not sure what other problems taking them out will cause.
BUT by doing this I finally got rid of the "SystemError: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException" and was able to make an instance of the Kkma() class and use it, so if that's all you need then hopefully this is enough :]